# Can't cross compile(windows) a program that link ssl library

Tags: c, windows, gcc, ssl, openssl

I have a C program that link the ssl library(`md5.h`) :

```
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#  define COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL
#  include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#  define SHA1 CC_SHA1
#else
#  include <openssl/md5.h>
#endif
```

every thing works fine on Linux and Mac Os X, compiling with this command line :

```
gcc program.c -o prog -lssl
```

Now i want to compile it for windows, so i have installed MinGw on my Debian, and i'm trying to cross compile with this command line :

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc program.c -o program.exe -lssl
```

but i get this compilation  error :

> error: openssl/md5.h: No such file or directory

Why? How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need OpenSSL built for Windows where the compiler can find it.
The easiest way is to build from source, and install into a prefix the mingw compiler can find it (or pass the include and library paths to your build system).

OpenSSL is a third party lib, so it's not part of the mingw package.

Comment: I have placed the library in the /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/, but it gives me the above error anyway...

Comment: @aleroot placing the library (I hope one compiled with mingw, not the Linux one) is good, but you need to have the openSSL headers in `/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include` for the compiler to find it. The library is needed only when linking, the headers are needed to compile the code.

Comment: You were right, it was caused by missing openssl header files.

Answer (score 0):

Check all paths in makefile.m32 files, there must be something wrong with them.

And AFAIR you must compile it not in cmd, but in mingw-cmd, that installs along with mingw package.

Comment: He's compiling on Linux, there's no mention or availability of `cmd`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that, sorry :(  Anyway he must check paths in makefile.m32, that error points that there is big possibility something is wrong with them